# Is it possible to call Javascript function in parent document from JS in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Both the iframe and the parent document are on the same domain. What I would like to do is give the js running in the iframe a callback function that resides in the parent document. Is this possible?

```
      window.frames["testFrame"].org.myorg.events.onDataReady.addListener(function (e) {
                alert("Data ready!");
}
```

I would like "testFrame" to call the anonymous function. The above js would be in the parent document. Is this possible?

Thanks.
**Update**

The following works:

```
$(document).read(function(){
   $(frameObj).load(function () {
                window.frames["testFrame"].org.myorg.events.onDataReady.addListener(function (e) {
                    var doc = $("#summaryFrame")[0].contentDocument;
                    doc.open();
                    doc.writeln(e.data.summaryHtml);
                    doc.close();
                });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: David - actually I think it will work.. the problem is I am trying to run this code after the frame loads $("#myFrame").load()

Comment: "Yes". But generally not cross-site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can - I've done this many times before in a previous job (... their "software" was basically 1,000 frames and a tabbed document).

Assuming you have this code in your top frame:

```
function blah() { alert("it worked!"); }
```

You can call this in the iframe...

```
top.blah();
```

Also, you can have the parent call down into the child, but the other way around is easier in my opinion.

Comment: Exaaaaactly :) (but if I said that you would have been mad at me)