# Functions() out of iframe?

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to call Javascript function in parent document from JS in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005318/is-it-possible-to-call-javascript-function-in-parent-document-from-js-in-iframe)

I have a `main.php` page.

This contains an iframe which `src` is `random.php`.

How can I have script in the `main.php` with a random function, `random()`, and let `random.php` use that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with HTML5, you can use the `postMessage()` function..

here is a nice demo:

http://html5demos.com/postmessage

**UPDATE**

The idea is to `postMessage` to the iframe `window` object, each window is listening to the message event like so:

In your main.php:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    var data = e.data; // data can be any object for example { type: 'random', payload: {}... }
    switch(data.type){
        case 'random':
            // do somthing here with the payload...
            break;
    }
});
```

in your iframe (random.php):

```
window.parent.postMessage({ type: 'random', payload: {...} });
```

Comment: how is that helpful in using functions

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function `random` in the page that contains the `iframe` using `window.parent.random()`. If you want to do the opposite, namely calling a function in an (`i`)`frame` from a containing page, you should use `[DOM Reference to frame].contentWindow.random()` instead.

↪ [More information about `window.parent` at the Mozilla Developer wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent)

---

If `random.php` is at a different domain, you can't do this because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). If that's the case, you can use HTML5 [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to transfer information across pages*. This does not allow you to directly call functions of a different domain's JavaScript, however.

<sub>* See [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) for browser support information</sub>